# multiple threads changes on a member doesn't reflect in the main thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c++-cli

may I have the community's opinion here. I have an application in which I have multiple threads accessing a member of a (this) class, the class that invoked the thread itself. The problem is that when the new thread adds an element in a LinkedList member, I can see that the LinkedList's count is increased to 1 as a result of the added element, however in the main thread the changes made by the new thread was not reflected. I even passed the reference of the current object to ParameterizedThreadStart, but it's still not working.

**illustration:**

```
ParameterizedThreadStart^ pReceiveProc = gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(this, &ActualClass::Receive);
Thread^ pReceiveThread = gcnew Thread(pReceiveProc);
pReceiveThread->Start(this); // passed the current instance
```

**the thread method:**

```
void Receive(Object^ pObj) {
    ActualClass^ l_Cls = dynamic_cast<ActualClass^>(pObj);
    l_Cls->MyLinkList->AddLast("test");
    Console::WriteLine("{0}", l_Cls->MyLinkList->Count); //outputs 1
}
```

**but if I access MyLinkList from the main thread:**

```
void MethodMainThread(){
    Console::WriteLine("{0}", MyLinkList->Count); //outputs 0
}
```

A static member solution is not an option.

Comment: in the context of MethodMainThread(), are you sure the variable l_Cls still references the same list you've passed to the other thread?

Comment: yes, because I have always passed the "this" reference of the main thread, I've edited my post, MethodMainThread don't have l_Cls by the way, as it is the main thread so it should access the MyLinkList directly

Comment: what does your main program looks like? are you checking the count really after the element has been inserted? and be aware that LinkedList is not thread-safe so use a lock

Comment: yeah, I'm checking after the element is inserted, because I'm doing this manually in a unit test, and yes I'm using a Monitor to lock the link list on each read/write

Answer (score 1):

most propably , your secondary thread gets preempted and your main thread checks for count and then secondary thread adds an object , try to use signaling , and let the main thread wait till the secondary thread completed its operation.

Comment: Hmmm.. this could be unlikely, since I was manually tracing it in Unit test, so I'll let the secondary thread finish first before running the test that will call the method in the main thread

Comment: but an Unit Test run on seprate thread itself. check without using thread , just single thread may be there is some other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can't share data between threads just like that. A simple approach to it is using the 'lock' statement. It is rather straightforward and [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) a good explanation.